# Azure Active Airectory (AAD) Service to Service Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

i am building a web application which should be able to create new users in a Office365 directory through Azure AD.

Users enter the site anonymous, but got a token-code before (in person exchange) to verify they are allowed to access the site. Users enter a number of contact information (Name, Location etc), the token code and when they submit the form, the app creates the new account.

The issue:
The authentication and permissions to create objects in the AAD for the Office365 org are needed. I already registered the app and got the authentication working on an account level. The problem is, I am unsure where to start the service-to-service authentication int the MVC5 template I am using?

I think usually one would request the token for Azure AD using the pre-shared secret via the Office365 graph API and then then use this token in subsequent requests?

Is there an example someone could share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track for doing this. You need to do the following steps:

- In your AD, you will need to create an "Application" for your web application (I think you've done this already)
- On the "Configure" tab of the application, you have to assign Application Permissions to the Windows Azure Active Directory pre-existing application, in your case your application probably needs the full `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission, which translates to "Read and write directory data" in the Azure Portal
- Create a new key for your application (if you haven't already)

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes

Now you're set to do the Client Credentials flow with the Graph API in order to access the Azure AD REST API: Do a `POST` to the following end point:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/(your AD tenant ID)/oauth2/token
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=(your webapp client id)
&client_secret=(the key you just created)
&resource=https://graph.windows.net
```

This request will (hopefully) give you an access token back which enables you to talk to the Graph API.

I bet you can do this using ADAL or similar SDKs, too, but this is what happens in the background.

Using the access token as your `Authorization` header content, you can now access the Graph API as described in the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview), e.g like this:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/(your AD domain)/users?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...
```

Which will return a response like this:

```
200 OK

{
  "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/(your domain ID)/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
  "value": [
    {
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
      "objectType": "User",
      "objectId": "(some GUID)",
      "deletionTimestamp": null,
      "accountEnabled": true,
....
```

Posting to the `/users?api-version=1.5` endpoint will create users for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you that is a very helpful summary. I got an implementation which successfully acquired a valid token. I guess the part which i am confused about is how to do the POST for user creation.

Comment: If you use "/oauth2/v2.0/token" endpoint the "&resource" request parameter is not supported (I use "scope" instead)